# What is wrong with this Haskell? "Parse error on input '='"

Tags: haskell, syntax, indentation

I keep getting this error message and I don't understand why:

```
src\Parsing.hs:21:18: parse error on input `='
```

It is coming from this line:

```
tokens  = map strip $ splitWhen (== delimiter) line
```

MY CODE:

```
tokenize :: String -> HashMap String String
tokenize line = 
   let (delimiter, fieldOrder) = delimiterAndFieldOrderFor line
           tokens  = map strip $ splitWhen (== delimiter) line
   in Map.fromList $  zip fieldOrder tokens

delimiterAndFieldOrderFor :: String -> (Char, [String])
delimiterAndFieldOrderFor line    
       | isInfixOf "," line = (',', ["LastName", "FirstName", "Gender", "FavoriteColor", "BirthDate"])    
       | isInfixOf "|" line = ('|', ["LastName", "FirstName", "Ignored", "Gender", "FavoriteColor", "BirthDate"])    
       | otherwise          = (' ', ["LastName", "FirstName", "Ignored", "Gender", "BirthDate", "FavoriteColor"])
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm beginning to think the FAQ should say "Parse error? Indentation.  Type Error?  Remove your explicit signatures."  Not ment as a personal jab, Alex, but these questions come up a whole lot and I don't think SO has a good system for discussion of community issues.

Comment: Yep.  I even tried to fix the indentation.  Took me a while to realize Leksah was altering the indentation, on save!  So... doubly confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indentation.

On line 4, `tokens` should be indented to the same depth as the parens that starts `(delim...`). E.g.

```
tokenize line = 
   let (delimiter, fieldOrder) = delimiterAndFieldOrderFor line
       tokens  = map strip $ splitWhen (== delimiter) line
   in Map.fromList $  zip fieldOrder tokens
```

You might also consider using a `where` clause:

```
tokenize line = Map.fromList $ zip f tokens
   where
       (sep, f) = delimiterAndFieldOrderFor line
       tokens   = map strip $ splitWhen (== sep) line
```

as a matter of style, those very long names for variables are a bit obfuscating, IMO.

Comment: I just realized the Leksah keeps changing the indentation.  If I change the file in Notepad++, then it runs fine.  Weird.

Answer (score 1):

You have extra indentation in this code:

```
let (delimiter, fieldOrder) = delimiterAndFieldOrderFor line
       tokens  = map strip $ splitWhen (== delimiter) line
in Map.fromList $  zip fieldOrder tokens
```

This causes the compiler to treat the line as a continuation of the expression on the line above it. It should be

```
let (delimiter, fieldOrder) = delimiterAndFieldOrderFor line
    tokens  = map strip $ splitWhen (== delimiter) line
in Map.fromList $  zip fieldOrder tokens
```